# Converting Two's complement to denary in Java

Tags: java, binary, twos-complement

I am writing a program to do number system conversions. 
The problem I am having is when I input a two's complement number Java is taking it in as a positive binary number for example if I input 11111101 as -3 instead the program takes in 253. how can i make it so the program takes in -3.

Comment: `if (n > 127) n -= 256;`

Comment: You could cast to `byte` if you're only dealing with 8-bit numbers, if not I could post some more general sign-extensions

Comment: @harold if you could post some more sign-extensions that would be nice; as I'm allowing the user to input the number so it could be higher than 8-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Though not addressing the title directly, sign-extending your input is a step towards that goal. Here are some ways to sign-extend that work in a more general case, not just when the input is 8 or 16 or 32 bits.

- Relying on arithmetic right shift: `(x << k) >> k` where `k` is the number of "unused" bits. So for example to extend an 8-bit number into a 32-bit number, `k` would be 24.
- A XOR trick: `(x ^ m) - m`, where `m` is a mask that has a 1 exactly where the signbit of your input is. Eg for 8-bit input, `m = 1 << 7`. Advantage is that it depends only on the input, not the type you're converting to - for Java that's not really a consideration, but that makes it attractive for use in templated C++ code.
- Explicit wrapping, like jsheeran's comment.